# First-derivative of vector

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I have got a dataframe with spectral absorbance values (A) at various wavelengths (λ) and want to get the first (and later second derivative) of those values.

In [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2799609/) it says:

"[...] Construction of First-Order Derivative Spectrum [...]: 
The absorbance values (A) at various wavelengths (λ; ranging from 200 to 400 nm) of each standard solution was used to calculate the slope of the tangent equation $\frac{(dA)}{dλ}$ at each data point and plot of equation $\frac{dA}{dλ}$ against λ generated the corresponding first-order derivative spectra.

Right now I don't know what to do with my values to get those $\frac{(dA)}{dλ}$ values. Has this something to do with difference in following wavelengths? I know its simple (and basic) mathematics but I don't know any further...

I expect my results when plotted to look like the plots on [this site](http://www.ascanis.de/UV_Vis_NIR_Themen/Derivativ-Spektrometrie/derivativ-spektrometrie.html), where the red line shows my original spectral data and the blue line the corresponding derivative data (first to fourth order; D1-D4).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a data set $\bigl(\lambda_k,A_k\bigr)_{1\leq k\leq N}$. These data "belong" to a function $A: \>\lambda\mapsto A(\lambda)$, but are probably containing numerical errors. You are looking for information about the function $\lambda\mapsto A'(\lambda)$. This information can only be numerical, and its validity depends on the quality of your data and the smoothness of the function $\lambda\mapsto A(\lambda)$. It follows that your problem is *numerical*. Look up [numerical differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation) or your textbook on numerical analysis.

Comment: But like on my second link given the upper left diagram for example:
The red line is plotted absorbance data against wavelength.
How do I get the first derivation of this data (blue line)?

Comment: Look up numerical differentiation (in Wikipedia) or your textbook on numerical analysis.